# print only first column of the tabular output in php/python

Tags: python, php, linux

Not sure if the title justifies what I'm looking for.
I'm new to PHP and Python. I'm writing a code in PHP. on execution which gives output in tabular form (rows and columns). 
I just want to print only the first word of each row ie first column. I searched a lot to find a way in the internet but hard luck. How to do it in PHP or Python?
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See explode() function of php.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried along with example input/output?

Answer (score 0):

In Python let's say your output is a list of list(i.e tabular).
example

```
l = [['first_word','A','B'], ['second_word','C','D']]
output = [x[0] for x in l]
print(output)
>>> ['first_word', 'second_word']
```